# ssh "port 22: no route to host" error in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sed

I wrote a scipt to execute a couple of ssh remote comands relating to apache storm. When I execute the script it says:

```
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 22: Connection refused
```

If I execute the commands manually it works out well and I can ping the machine. So that there has to be something wrong with this code:

```
while [ $i -le $numVM ]

do
    if [ $i -eq 1 ];then
        ssh -i file root@IP1 './zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh start' 
    else
        ssh -i file root@IP2 'sed -i '"'"'s/#\ storm.zookeeper.servers.*/storm.zookeeper.servers:/'"'"' /root/apache-storm-0.9.3/conf/storm.yaml'
        ssh -i file root@IP2 'sed -i '"'"'0,/^#[[:space:]]*-[[:space:]]*\"server1\".*/s//"      - \"'${IParray[1]}'\""/'"'"' /root/apache-storm-0.9.3/conf/storm.yaml'
        ssh -i file root@IP2 'sed -i '"'"'s/#\ nimbus.host:.*/"nimbus.host: \"'${IParray[2]}'\""/'"'"' /root/apache-storm-0.9.3/conf/storm.yaml'
        ssh -i file root@IP2 './zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkCli.sh -server ${IParray[1]} &'
        sleep 10
        ssh -i file root@IP2 './apache-storm-0.9.3/bin/storm nimbus &' &
        sleep 10
        ssh -i file root@IP2 './apache-storm-0.9.3/bin/storm ui &' & 
        sleep 10
        ssh -i file root@IP2 './apache-storm-0.9.3/bin/storm supervisor &' &
    fi  
    ((i++))
done
```

I'm starting several processes on 2 virtual machines that are deployed from the same image, so that they are identical in general. The confusing part is, that the first ssh command (zkServer.sh start) is working well but if I the script tries to execute the three "sed"-ssh-commands I get the error message above. But then the last four ssh-commands are working out well again. That does not make any sense to me...

Comment: Try printing out the command before executing it or using `set -x` to have bash show you what it's doing at every step.  Perhaps one of the variables is not expanding the way you expect?  I see that in some lines you have `$IP2` and others you just have `IP2` perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: No actually it is an array (${IParray[$i]}) I used IP1 and IP2 to make it short and clearer to others. But I will try set -x and check what the script does in detail. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Ok, I checked it. The bash output of the command seems fine, again after the execution it says "no route to host". I copied the command and executed it manually and it works. How is that even possible?

Comment: Any chance your array has some unprintable characters in it, like a `\r` at the end of IP2 that isn't there for IP1?

Comment: No, in that case when I copy the command showing up because of "set -x", it should not work out aswell I think. But it does so that the command is right in general?

Answer (score -1):

Several things I can think of:

- Most `sshd` daemons won't allow `root` access. Heck, many versions of Unix/Linux no longer allow root login. If you need root access, you need to use `sudo`.
- The `sshd` daemon on the remote machine isn't running. Although rare, some sites may never had it setup, or purposefully shut it off as a security issue.
- Your `ssh` commands themselves are incorrect.

Instead of executing the `ssh` commands in your shell script, modify the shell script just to print out what you're attempting to execute. Then, see if you can execute the command **outside** of the shell script. This way you can determine whether the problem is the shell script, or the problem is with the `ssh` command itself.

If your `ssh` commands don't work **outside** from the command line, you can then simplify them and see if you can determine what the issue could be. You have `ssh -i file root@IP2`. Is this suppose to be `ssh -i $file root@$IP2`? (i.e., you're missing the leading sigil).

```
$ ssh -i file root@$IP2 ls   # Can't get simpler than this...
$ ssh -i file root@IPS       # See if you can remotely log on...
$ ssh root@IP2               # Try it without an 'identity file'
$ ssh bob@IP2                # Try it as a user other than 'root'
$ telnet IP2 22              # Is port 22 even open on the remote machine?
```

If these don't work, then you have some very basic issue with the setup of your remote machine's `sshd` command.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I want to directly give you my opinion to them. I am running many many ssh-commands with "root" and as I mentioned in my question there are ssh-commands working with root even in this script. From my point of view that would not be possible if the sshd daemon is not running. Once again to really make it clear, **only** the _sed_ commands do not work. To your last point, I would also say that is not the case. Because as I mentioned in a comment, if I execute exactly the same command out of the shell script, it works. Telnet is working fine...

Comment: It's just the sed? Why not use `ssh -i file root@IP2 "sed -i 's/#\ sto.../' /root/apache-storm-0.9.3/conf/storm.yaml"`. That is, surround your `ssh` command with double quotes instead of single quotes. Then single quotes will work in your `sed` command without having to _quote_ them with other quotes. You can also try `\'` instead of `'"'"'`.

Comment: I tried it with double quotas, still no route to host. But I figured out something strange. If I copy the sed-commands into another script it works. So I would say the commands are correct, there has to be something wrong with the executing script maybe? When I close the 2 VMs I get _Connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX closed by remote host._ even if I am not on the machine right now. Could this might be related to the error in any way?

Comment: How are you initiating the script automatically?  If using cron(1) / cronie(1) and friends, keep in mind the runtime environment does not automatically run any shell start-up scripts.  Also, from cron(1), there won't be a stdin/pty input connected.